# bash rsync can't find directory with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

I am trying to make a backup script and the problem is that it can't find the directory that has spaces in it.

Code for bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

Desk="/Users/elev/Desktop/"

include_paths=(
    "${Desk}/Skola"
    "${Desk}/music"
    "${Desk}/jobb"
    # not working directory
    "${Desk}/programmering\ skola"

)

# ${include_paths[@]} means every value in the list
for item in "${include_paths[@]}"
do
    include_args="${include_args} ${item}"

done

DestPath="/Volumes/Atheer/backup"

rsync -av --delete ${include_args} $DestPath
```

as you can see I have tried to use backslash and space, still it doesn't work. I get the following error code **rsync: link_stat "/Users/elev/Desktop/programmering\" failed: No such file or directory** 
I would like it to backup directories that have spaces in them too. I appreciate the help

Comment: Do not ever use string concatenation to form commands. This is discussed in detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Also, it should just be `"${Desk}/programmering skola"`, with no backslash literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know how to use arrays. You should use them more. :)

```
rsync -av --delete "${include_paths[@]}" "$DestPath"
```

`"${include_paths[@]}"` (the quotes are essential!) expands each element in the `include_paths` array to a separate `rsync` argument.

There's no reason to generate `include_args` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another bug:

```
 "${Desk}/programmering\ skola"
```

Try

```
 "${Desk}/programmering skola"
```

extract from `man bash` for double quotes:

> The  backslash  retains  its  special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: $, `, ", \, or newline.